# Problems with Text Manipulation in an Action with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, actions

I'm on an old Mac running Mojave and Illustrator 25.4.1

I have 586 AI Files that all need to have these two changes in all the files with an Action:

1. Delete two text objects in a layer (Named "Card Type") that were somehow duplicated from another layer (called "Copyright"). There are three text objects and I need to delete only two of them. Can't figure out how to select the two text objects without selecting the third.
2. In the "Copyright" layer, I then need to update the text in just one of two text objects. Selecting the text with the text tool and typing in the new info. doesn't record. Also, for most of the files, the text is black. But some of the files have the copyright info in white.

Please help!

Comment: I don't think you can do either with actions. Actions can't "read" text, you would need scripting to pull text contents.